# Is it Basic Physics?

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, game, physics

Which number is next in the sequence?

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ...

Describe **why** and **how** your answer applies to the given problem.

Comment: This problem is too open. Vote to close!

Comment: I have so many questions

Comment: I'm betting that there's more to this than meets the eye; @Chowzen do you, in good faith, think it should be reopened? (I know you said "Vote to close!" but guess that's part of some joke.)

Comment: I applaud the person who upvoted my comment on closing.

Comment: Too broad? There are *zero* answers. Perhaps from the closing?

Comment: My problem with this question is that it will attract a lot of speculation. There is no context on how to go about solving this other than some numbers and a link to physics. The "lateral-thinking" tag can lead people to make up physical scenarios or use numbers magic to create multiple feasible solutions. Some slight rewording or a nudge to the field of physics that this relates to would save this question

Comment: The last thing stack exchange needs is interest.

Comment: You can probably fix this by adding some story. Since I gather there is a physics connection, have a student and teacher conversing. Present the first part of the sequence and have the student think it's just the positive integers, have them be wrong about 8, keep going, and then have the student realize after 15 "oh, I get it!" - this flavour text will ideally include a few hidden puns that confirm everything for those who know what you're referring to. Then it's a good puzzle.

Comment: actually please **just** notice that 8 is missing from the sequence. thanks! i'm supporting reopening of this question because i believe that there is something people haven't found and therefore VTC-ed them. please observe before deciding. thank you!

Comment: Is the order of the fourteen numbers important, and may the game tag include sports related games?

Comment: @Tom The order is precise. You may interpret "game" as you wish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sequence continues

> with eight, and then stops.

because they are

> playing [eight-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-ball), which has fifteen balls, but you're supposed to sink eight last. I guess the game went like this: the first player sank the first seven (solids), but missed the eight. Then the second player got the next seven (stripes). And then got the eight to win. Or, the second player also missed the eight, and then the first player got the eight to win on the next attempt.

Comment: Is it possible that this can explain the (rot13) fcnpvat orgjrra gur pbzznf?

Comment: @Jay - I did not even notice that! hmmm.

Comment: Not really sure where the physics tag comes in, unless it's in the rot13(zbirzrag bs gur onyyf).

Comment: Maybe the title refers to rot13(Jung tbrf hc, zhfg pbzr qbja.)